# Spectron testing producing a JScript syntax error

Tags: json, node.js, electron, spectron

I'm trying to test out spectron for electron in terms of testing but as I'm going through a tutorial, I keep getting this error message whenever I run **npm run test:e2e**. My test file syntactically correct but im not sure why i run into an error through compilation

Specs:

- Nodejs 6.10.3
- Electron 1.6.1

[here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcPB5.png)

here's the json file **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "C:/Users/Livs/Documents/imdc/logger/node_modules/.bin/electron .",
    "test:e2e": "C:/Users/Livs/Documents/imdc/logger/test.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-chromedriver": "^1.7.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.11",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
    "electron": "^1.3.4",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "spectron": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Heres the testing file **test.js**

```
const Application = require('spectron').Application;
const path = require('path');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

var electronPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '.bin',     'electron');

if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    electronPath += '.cmd';
}

var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..');

var app = new Application({
            path: electronPath,
            args: [appPath]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `npm run e2e` just calls the `test.js` file. You'll need a test runner, `mocha` for instance. Then you would run `mocha test.js`. Or change the e2e script inside `package.json` to run that command.

All your file paths for the scripts inside `package.json` should be relative to the package root, ie `logger/test.js`. Regarding the npm bins you only need to type the bin name, ie `electron`.

To solve your problem you should change your package.json `test:e2e` command to `mocha test.js`.

(You can also change your `start` command to `electron .` since custom npm commands will always look for binaries in `./node_modules/.bin`